# GetOptions() to enforce choice of strings

Tags: perl

I have been unable to formulate a search phrase for this so you have my apologies if this has been asked already.  (Likely has been.)

Among my options to a new Perl utility I'm writing is a --sortby option.  The available choices I'm giving the user are:

- --sortby TID
- --sortby SID

Now it's really *very* easy for me to implement this after the GetOptions call, merely by checking if ($opt_sortby eq "SID" || $opt_sortby eq "SID"). (Actually, I've coded that a bit more elegantly but that's another issue.)  But I'm trying to push my knowledge and see if I can force this choice to be enforced by GetOptions, something like

```
GetOptions('sortby=s'  => {"SID" | "TID"});
```

Please note that I'm merely using notation commonly used in documentation to represent a mandatory "one of these" choice.  I don't really expect this exact syntax in GetOptions.

Ideas anyone?

Thanks mucho. (Szépen köszönöm, in case G.S. answers :-)

-- Jacob S.

Comment: You can handle options with a [custom subroutine](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#User-defined-subroutines-to-handle-options), but I don't see why you would complicate things for the simple example you've given. Calling `die unless $opt_sortby eq 'SID' || $opt_sortby eq 'TID';` after `GetOptions` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Checking after `GetOptions` returns is quite simple.

```
my %valid_sort_by = map { $_ => 1 } qw( SID TID );

GetOptions('sortby=s' => \$opt_sort_by)
   or usage();

if (defined($valid_sort_by)) {
   $valid_sort_by{$opt_sort_by}
      or usage("Invalid value for --sortby\n");
}
```

It's more complicated, but you can achieve what you asked using a callback.

```
my %valid_sort_by = map { $_ => 1 } qw( SID TID );

GetOptions(
   'sortby=s' => sub {
      my ($opt_name, $opt_value) = @_;
      $valid_sort_by{$opt_value}
         or die("Invalid value for --$opt_name\n");
      $opt_sort_by = $opt_value;
   },
)
   or usage();
```

The advantage of the latter is that it will detect the error in

```
command --sortby=bad --sortby=SID
```

Comment: Ikegami,
Your first solution, with the hash keyed on valid choices, is SO COOL!

I used this:
my @choices = qw(SID TID USER);
GetOptions(...)
die "Wrong sortby choice) unless (inlist($opt_sortby, \@choices);
# inlist() is a library function.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use [Getopt::Declare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Declare). It has support for enumeration of values:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use Getopt::Declare;

my $args = Getopt::Declare->new(
   join( "\n",
      "--sort-by <s:/SID|TID/>\t field to sort by, valid options are TID, SID [required]"
   )
) or exit(1);
```

and then to use from the command line:

```
$ perl test.pl --sort-by TID
$ perl test.pl --sort-by SID
$ perl test.pl --sort-by FID
Error: incorrect specification of '--sort-by' parameter
Error: required parameter --sort-by not found.

(try 'test.pl -help' for more information)
```

Getopt::Declare has a built-in --help option that will show the specification as well:

```
$ perl test.pl --help

Usage: test.pl [options]  --sort-by <s> 
       test.pl -help
       test.pl -version

Options:
--sort-by <s>            field to sort by, valid options are TID, SID
```

Comment: you have done me two services: Introducing me to to Getopt::Declare and convincing me to stick with my current method, which is to check $opt_sortby after the GetOptions call.  "Designed to be exceptionally easy to use" indeed!    But it is something to keep in mind for more complicated cases; you never know when the need will arise.  Thanks, Hunter!